# Как привязать к keybinding.command к viewmodel, когда у меня textbox уже привязан к models. Мне нужно чтобы по нажатию Enter создавался новый элемент

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding, avalonia

Как привязать к keybinding.command к viewmodel, когда у меня textbox уже привязан к models. Мне нужно чтобы по нажатию Enter создавался новый элемент

```xml
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="using:Testing_ItemsControl.ViewModels"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Testing_ItemsControl.Models"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="Testing_ItemsControl.Views.MainWindow"
        x:DataType="vm:MainWindowViewModel"
        Icon="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"
        Title="Testing_ItemsControl">

    <Design.DataContext>
        <!-- This only sets the DataContext for the previewer in an IDE,
             to set the actual DataContext for runtime, set the DataContext property in code (look at App.axaml.cs) -->
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Design.DataContext>

    <StackPanel Margin="20">
        <TextBlock Margin="0 5">List of crockery:</TextBlock>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CrockeryList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Margin="0,10,0,0"
                            CornerRadius="5"
                            BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1"
                            Padding="5">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Number, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                <TextBox.KeyBindings>
                                    <KeyBinding Gesture="Enter" Command="{Binding Source={}}"></KeyBinding>
                                </TextBox.KeyBindings>
                            </TextBox>
                            <!-- <TextBox Text="{Binding DataType=models:Crockery, Path=(models:Crockery).Title}"></TextBox> -->
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <Button Content="Create new item" Command="{Binding CreateItem}">
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Вот models

```
namespace Testing_ItemsControl.Models;

public class Crockery
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Number{ get; set; }

    public Crockery(string title, int number)
    {
        Title = title;
        Number = number;
        
    }
}
```

вот viewmodels

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Crockery> CrockeryList { get; set; }
    public ReactiveCommand <Unit, Unit> CreateItem { get; }
        
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        CrockeryList = new ObservableCollection<Crockery>(new List<Crockery>());
        
        CreateItem = ReactiveCommand.Create(() =>
        {
            CrockeryList.Add(new Crockery("sad", 22));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: То есть мне нужно как-то внутри textbox'a изменить datacontext, потому-что он привязан к моей модели